# RandomFileAccess - java.io.StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, serialization, io, deserialization, randomaccessfile

I am trying to read 'n' bytes (serialized object) from file starting from position 'i' using. Here is my code snippet below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
      String s = "XYZ";
      RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("/home/Test.txt", "rw");
      f.write(s.getBytes());
      FingerPrint finger = new FingerPrint("ABCDEFG", "ABCD.com");
      Serializer ser = new Serializer();
      byte[] key = ser.serialize(finger);//Serializing the object
      f.seek(3);
      f.write(key);
      byte[] new1 = new byte[(int)f.length()-3];
      int i=0;
      for(i=3;f.read()!=-1;i++){
        f.seek(i);
        new1[i]=f.readByte();
      }
      FingerPrint finger2 = (FingerPrint) ser.deserialize(new1);//deserializing it
      System.out.println("After reading:"+finger2.getURL());
}
```

I am getting following exception,

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:807)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:302)
```

Here is my serializer class,

```
class Serializer {

public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
        try(ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b)){
            o.writeObject(obj);
        }
        return b.toByteArray();
    }
}

public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try(ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)){
        try(ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b)){
            return o.readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

}

If i don't write any string to the file, and only read the object i.e. start from 0 to eof, i am able to see the output. There are many such questions already asked but i want to know why it is not working when i write a object in particular location and read it back. May be i am doing something wrong, Please share your thoughts.

Comment: _"May be i am doing something wrong"_ -- quite likely. Did you examine the file in a hex editor to see what you actually wrote?

Comment: New to the domain. thanks for hex editor..downloaded.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Every object you serialize will have a serialization stream header prepended to it, and data for every class involved. Your file will be much larger than you think. Serialization is serial in nature, not random-access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
  f.seek(3);
  f.write(key);
  byte[] new1 = new byte[(int)f.length()-3];
  int i=0;
  for(i=3;f.read()!=-1;i++){
          ^^^^^^^^
```

At this point the file pointer is at EOF since you just wrote the serialized bytes and have not moved the file pointer yet.  This loop is unnecessary, you should `seek(3)` and then read directly into `new1` as in

```
byte[] new1 = new byte[(int) f.length() - 3];
f.seek(3);
f.read(new1);
FingerPrint finger2 = (FingerPrint) ser.deserialize(new1);// deserializing
```